# Data defined position of table in print composer (QGIS 2.18)

Tags: qgis, print-composer

As the screenshot below shows: the data defined position of the text field is working, but that of the table doesn't. Can anyone confirm this behavior?

[image]

Comment: It certainly looks like it should work. Dum question, but your 'box_pos' field is definitely 'right'? as it appears the expression is fulfilling the ELSE clause.

Comment: The table has the same expression as the text field. The text field is working.

Comment: How do you get a field for an attribute table, an HTML frame or a text box for that matter?

Comment: Perhaps a bug? When you type in your expression, there is a `Fields and Values` category just below `Date and Time` in your image. Does it recognise any fields at all? Mine does not which means you cannot create expressions using fields. Tested on QGIS 2.18.0 and 2.16.1.

Comment: Yes, it does, all fields are recognized.

Answer (score 1):

I replicated this in QGIS 2.14.4 Essen. It seems to act the way you describe until you Generate an Atlas. Up until that moment the expression always returned false, probably because it didn't recognize the columns in the layer. Once i generated an atlas the attribute table "jumped" from 10mm to 200mm. When i then checked the position options it recocgnized the columns and the values correctly.

Comment: I can confirm that. In QGIS Essen the data defined positioning in 'Atlas-Mode' seems to be working as it should. So it's worth to place a bug report...

Comment: Placed a Bug report: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/16064#change-74118 and still need a solution...